# % Cover of polygons within radius of points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, land-cover

I Have a polygon layer representing multiple sites in a city.

I want to calculate the combined % cover of all sites within buffered regions around points.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of....

1. buffer points to radius x
2. add new field to buffer file to calculate the area of the buffers: calculate geometry
3. Intersect new buffers with original polygon file (join attributes, you need the ID of the buffer on each polygon)
4. make a new area attribute field on your intersected polygons and calculate the new area
5. dissolve the intersected polygons shapefile, dissolve field is the buffer ID and the statistic is SUM of the area you just calculated in step 4

you can now join this sum of polygon areas per buffer ID back to the buffer shapefile or just calculate it wherever, simple percentage.

Comment: Thankyou, this worked a charm. Calculate geometry was not required though, Shape area was calculated automatically when layers were intersected.

Comment: ok no problem, but just be absolutely sure it's the area of the newly clipped polygons and not their original area (simply carried into the newly create shapefile)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at ArcScripts yet? A quick look at that threw up the following [tools](http://arcscripts.arcgis.com/#search%3Dcount%20overlapping%7Csoftware%3DAll%20Esri%20Software%7Clanguage%3DAll%20Languages%7CresultType%3D(type%3A%22code%20samples%22%20OR%20type%3A%22add-ins%22%20OR%20type%3A%22geoprocessing%20samples%22)%7CitemsPerPage%3D10%7Cpage%3D1).

As a side note you should always look there first for this sort of question as ArcScripts has been around for years with thousands of user contributions.